# 指定したdiv要素の子要素=tableの、更に子要素であるtrの数を知りたい

Tags: jquery, html5

皆様いつもお世話になっております。
標題の件、率直に言えば、以下HTMLで、table中のtrを削除したいのですが、class="appLineDummy"というtrは【除いた全て】を削除したいです。(DOMExporerの画像=が表れているのはこの為？！)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

div要素にはclass名が付いているので、こちらを起点とした処理を行うか、table中1行目のtrだけがclass名がついている状態なので、こちらを起点とした処理を行うか、になると思われます。

目的のtr要素数を得る上でlength();、子要素の参照にはchildren();、要素の削除にはremove();を利用する、という点までは認識できているのですが、
children();を使ってみた時点で　つまづいてしまったので今回のお問い合わせとなりました。

```
//***div要素の中で、tr要素 class="appLineDummy"ではないtr要素を全て削除 ***
//***一先ず何行あるか捉えてみる　↓ エラーになる***
    var rows = $(".appLines")[0].children().children();
    alert(rows.length + "行あります。");
```

## ====質問====

当初の計画は、標題の件の達成を、$.eachの利用で考えておりましたが、こちらの手順に拘りありません。皆様でしたら一体どういったコーディングで当目的を達成するのでしょうか？
厚かましいお願いですが、ヒントだけでも頂けましたら幸いです、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？

```js
function trRemove(){
/**
Class"appLines"をもった"div"：(div.appLines)
…の子孫にいる"table"：(table)
…の子孫にいる"tr"のClass"appLineDummy"を"持たない"要素：(tr:not(.appLineDummy))
**/
  var cnt = $("div.appLines table tr:not(.appLineDummy)").length;
  $("div.appLines table tr:not(.appLineDummy)").remove();
  console.log(cnt+"件のtrを削除しました。");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="trRemove()">指定のtrを削除</button>
<div class="appLines">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="appLineDummy"><td>１</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>２</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>３</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>４</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>５</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>６</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>７</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>８</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>９</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>10</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td>11</td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: いつもお世話になっております。ご支援をありがとうございます。
実は．．．appLineDummyというクラス名がついたtr以外は、別のJQueryで動的に生成された要素です。
早速コピペして適用したところ、カウントの表示も削除された行も0でした。これはどうにかなるものでしょうか？
甘えてすみません．．．．
（ご提示のスニペットは無事動作できたので、動的な要素に適用できない自分の未熟さが問題と思いました）

Comment: @saya24 すみません。よく見たらdivのクラスを間違えていました。直したのとコードにコメントを追記したのでjQueryのセレクタを解読してみてください

Comment: 動的な要素が問題かと思ったら違ったのですね。コメント内容、よく理解できました、また今後の糧になりました。いつもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

（本件については問題になりませんが）先の回答のように同じjQueryオブジェクトを複数回取得するのは望ましくありませんし、そもそも`remove`メソッドは削除したjQueryオブジェクトを返してくれるので、次のように記述するほうがベターだと思います。

```
var cnt = $("div.appLines table tr:not(.appLineDummy)").remove().length;
console.log(cnt+"件のtrを削除しました。");
```

Comment: ご見解ありがとうございます。まだまだ話についていけないので、ゆっくりご提案の方式を確認させて頂きます。